# Batch file to search for multiple file names from a .txt document. Photography sorting batch file

Tags: batch, automation

I'm hoping there's a way to automate what would be a very tedious process.

I've been given a .txt list of 201 photo file names that have the following naming scheme: P1020181.JPG
and am hoping there would be a way of using this list to auto locate and copy these selected images from the larger set to a subfolder "selects".

I'm very new to automation scripts and only have basic CMD knowledge, so any help would be amazing.
Thanks

Comment: OS? What tools do you haev at your displosal? There are many ways to do it, it depends on what you have. Are the images only in 1 folder? or in multiple folders?

Comment: I think [this should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163873/107537) solve your problem .

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].